# Why doesn't the button respond in the first click, and Why the menu disappear when it scale back to desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have ran into a bit of problem with my mobile naviagtion.

First, the dropdown menu wouldn't respond to the **first click** but it starts respond on the 2nd click and every click after.

Second, When I scale the browser back to desktop version, the navigation will disappear.

here is how my code set up in Codepen: http://bit.ly/1Bxskho

**HTML**

```
<nav id="main-nav">
     <a id="mobile-btn">Mobile Menus</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html" target="_self" class="visited">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="architectures.html" target="_self">Architectures</a></li>
       <li><a href="nature_phenomenons.html" target="_self">Nature's Phenomenons</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-nav{
    float: right;
}

#mobile-btn{
    display: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin: 20px;
    background: url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat -25px 0;
}

#main-nav ul{
    margin: 25px 0 0 0;
}

#main-nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#main-nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    color: #29abe1;
    font-family: 'Muli', san-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover, #main-nav ul li a.visited{
    color: #21b573;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {

    /* #main-nav & #mobile-btn */
    #mobile-btn{
        display: block;
        background: url(../images/sprite@2x.png) no-repeat -25px 0;
        background-size: 200px 200px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 20px;
    }

    #main-nav:hover #mobile-btn, #mobile-btn:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #main-nav ul, #main-nav ul li, #main-nav ul li a{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #main-nav ul{
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #21b573;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #21b573;
        -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #21b573;
        -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #21b573;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #21b573;
    }

    #main-nav ul li{
        padding: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #21b573;
    }

    #main-nav ul li a{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#mobile-btn').toggle(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('#main-nav ul').stop().slideDown();
            $('#main-nav').css({"background-color": "#21b573"});
            $('#mobile-btn').css({"background-position": "-65px 0"});
        })
    }, function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('#main-nav ul').stop().slideUp();
            $('#main-nav').css({"background-color": "#fff"});
            $('#mobile-btn').css({"background-position": "-25px 0"});
        })
    });
```

Comment: Put the code in the question itself.

Comment: The code for the htm, css, and js are kinda too long to post here. So I put a link to codepen where i set all the html, css, and js.

Comment: If it's too much, the question is probably too broad. Instead, reduce it to a minimum test case, and you may even find the solution in the process.

Comment: I have updated the question with the repsective codes. It is basically what I have on the Codepen link.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPxmjB) codepen

The `toggle` function which you have used is deprecated from 1.8 and removed from 1.9 (there is another method with same name but the functionality is different)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var open = false;
    function sliding(){
        if(open){
            $('#main-nav ul').stop().slideDown();
            $('#main-nav').css({"background-color": "#21b573"});
            $('#mobile-btn').css({"background-position": "-65px 0"});
        }
        else{
            $('#main-nav ul').stop().slideUp();
            $('#main-nav').css({"background-color": "#fff"});
            $('#mobile-btn').css({"background-position": "-25px 0"});
        }
        open = !open;
    }

    $('#mobile-btn').click(function(){
        sliding();
    })
}); //end ready
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem still remains while in the mobile screen. the dropdown menu doesn't respond to the first click. And, I notice the hidden mobile-btn is being display while on the desktop screen wide.

Comment: `mobile-btn` is getting displayed because of the style attribute which i have added.

Answer (score -1):

When you create an element, that element has CSS properties applied to it. Those properties can come through:

- inheritance from a parent
- application of a named class
- explicit setting from the style attribute of the element

When you query an element's style attribute, what you get is what was explicitly set through a previous application of style and not related to the CSS properties in effect on the element through the other mechanisms.

When you changed the CSS, you are accessing its style attribute.  The first click initializes the `style`, and the second click changes it.

To fix this, put the attributes that you wish to change to in another class rule, then use jQuery's `toggleClass()` method to add and remove that class.

Comment: So, it's the css media query actually interfering the functionality of `toggle()`?

Comment: No, actually it's not.  The `toggle()` works on every click, but the CSS only on click two.

Comment: That is not what I am seeing on my original codes. The toggle() does not replies the **very first click** every time the page get refreshed. So that was my problem for it. Anyway, I manage to fix that today. Your comments was quite helpful. Thank you very much. And I am posting the new code on bottom.